# Eclipse RCP / SWT: How do you detect mouse events that happen elsewhere on the system

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application that is making functional pop up boxes using shells similar to those in Eclipse IDE.

At present I am making them disappear when the mouse moves off of them, but this is proving difficult for our users to manage.

I'd like to replicate the behaviour of the Eclipse IDE popups that only disappear when the user interact with any part of the system that is not the popup. For example clicking on the windows task bar.

I just can't figure out how the shell knows that the user is doing something in windows, to make the box disappear.

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered listening to `SWT.FocusOut`? Or does it never even gain focus?

Comment: Is that how they do it in eclipse?! I could force it to gain focus first couldn't I?

Comment: I have no idea how they do it. And yes, you could force the focus on it.

Comment: I can't seem to trigger lose focus events from anywhere, so not sure this is the approach.

Comment: Well, if you only want it do disappear when the user clicks somewhere, that itself should trigger the focus loss. How are you listening to `SWT.FocusOut`?

Comment: added a listener using the SWT.FocusOut value to the shell and to the composite on the shell. Neither seem to trigger

Comment: Ok, there's a text box on my shell and that text box automatically gets the focus, so technically it';s that box that looses it, with multiple components that would be very difficult to maintain.

Comment: Yeah, you can listen to `SWT.Deactivate` and `SWT.Close` on the `Shell` to be notified when the user either navigates away from the `Shell` or closes it.

Comment: Let me know it my previous suggestion works.

Comment: It does seem to be working perfectly at the minute, thanks Baz.

Comment: Actually it's making it disappear, but it seems to be greed with the clicks. So if I click on another component in my application the box now vanishes but it steals the click so the component never receives it.

Comment: Please post the code you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for `SWT.Deactivate` and `SWT.Close` on the `Shell` to be notified when the user navigates away from it or closes it.